# Specific apply where fiter only to specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is my query

```
select  p.result ,
      (case when p.parameterID = 'AVA' then sum(p.Result) else 0 end) as [AVA],
      (case parameterId when '2D' then sum(p.Result) else 0 end) [2D], 
      (case parameterId when 'Sd' then sum(p.Result) else 0 end ) [Sd]      
  FROM  Table1 p 
   WHERE p.parameterID 
        in ('AVA', '2D', 'Sd') and p.ResultNo=-1
       and  ( p.result * 10000 < 1.0 )  
           group by 
          p.result,  p.parameterID
```

I in above query in where clause I am using ( p.result * 10000 < 1.0 )  and  evaluating it for every value where (p.result * 10000 < 1.0) 
My requirement is to change this query it should apply only [AVA] for p.result * 10000 < 1.0

I want in where clause ( p.result * 10000 < 1.0 ) should apply/check only column [AVA] it should not apply to all columns.

Comment: I don't see a column [AVA]

Comment: p.parameterID = 'AVA'   is the column

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WHERE p.parameterID 
        in ('AVA', '2D', 'Sd') and p.ResultNo=-1
       and 
       (
            ( p.parameterID  = 'AVA' AND p.result * 10000 < 1.0 )  OR ( p.parameterID  <> 'AVA' )
        ) 
           group by 
          p.result,  p.parameterID
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution replaced (case when p.parameterID = 'AVA' then sum(p.Result) else 0 end) as [AVA], with below line (case when p.ParameterId='AVA' then sum(CASE when (p.resultvalue * 1) < 1.0 then p.resultvalue else 0 end ) else 0 END) as [AVA] and removed ( p.result * 10000 < 1.0 ) from where clause